# How can I search in SQL Server date (dd-MM-yyyy) with DateTimePicker(MM-yyyy)?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database with date (dd-MM-yyyy), and Winforms with a DateTimePicker (MM-yyyy).

When I choose a date in the DateTimePicker, how I can search in the database?

```
var sqlcomm = new SqlCommand($"SELECT SUM(sales) FROM table_name WHERE date = '{dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-mmm")}'", conn);
```

ERROR:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Answer (score 1):

Use **PARAMETERS** - as you **always** should! Those prevent SQL injection and they also make it a lot easier to specify various data in various types.

Something like this:

```
string query = "SELECT SUM(sales) FROM table_name WHERE date = @someDate;";

SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@someDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

Nice, clean and safe code - no need to mess around with date formats and converting everything to string, no need to figure out how many single or double quotes to use - just nice, clean, proper ADO.NET code as it should be.

Comment: It isn't work for me. If i have in the database: 06.04.2019 and 05.04.2019.If i choose in date timepicker 04.2019. i got false data.

Comment: I have a datetimepicker with this properties:ShowUpDown= true, costum format: mm-yyyy. When i select a date in datetimepicker it send the actually date for the query.. how can i set this?

Comment: @keremark08: you're obviously only selecting month + Year - that's not a complete date, so it can't be found in the database. Try selecting **all** three parts of a date - day, month, year - and see if that works

Comment: So in database : 06.04.2019. and 05.04.2019. and 22.03.2019. 
What is the perfect choise to me if i want the show to 'user'  all data where 04.2019. ? I don't  have not any idea.